# (binary) Matrix completion with less known data

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, clustering, missing-data, recommender-system

Recently, I meet such problems, I call it `matrix completion` problem. For example, the row denotes the users and the column denotes items. And If one user like the item, then we give the value 1, if the user do not like the item, then give the value -1. Now, I have 95 users and 223 items, and I make such a matrix: 95-by-223. However, the known values are very limited, which is 635 `1(like)` and 202 `-1(un-like)`. The total matrix have 21,185 (95*223) 
values, so the values `[21185 - (635+202) = 20348]` need be predicted as {1, -1}.

I would like to know which method is more suitable such background problem? Binary recommendation system?

I have a initial idea, this is to build binary classification models using the adjacent matrix. For the dependent variables: put `like` as one class, and `both un-like and do not known ones` as another class; for the independent variables, I can use the similarity matrix as independent variable.

But my question is, is that suitable to put those `unknown one` as another class? is there better ways to solve this kind of questions?

If I just used the known ones (`635` and `202`) to build model and then predicted the `unknown ones`, is this better than using `all data` like I mentioned before?

How do you consider such problem?

Comment: This is imputation of missing values problem. However the problem in your case is that you have too far much missing data (96%). They recommend to venture imput with less then about 15% of missing data only. Moreover, you have many more items than observations. That means that those 4% values that you have represent only a tiny portion of expected correlational patterns. My conclusion is that nothing can help your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Imputing methods look no way. Can you point me the reference which say `They recommend to venture imput with less then about 15% of missing data only`. I will learn it.

Comment: @ttnphns It is difficult to see why this necessarily is a missing value imputation problem: that would imply every user would be expected to supply a valid opinion about every item, which would be a rare occurrence indeed (unless the users were hired testers).  Isn't this basically the [Netflix recommendation problem?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflix_Prize)